# Firestore still take the same time in offline mode as compere to online

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment in android where I read some data from firestore and than present it in the recycler view. the thing is it still working slow the same when device is go offline. I see in documentation that data persistence is on by default in firestore. here is the code:

```
 firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
            .document(FirebaseAuthRepository().getCurrentUserId())
            .collection("categories")
            .get().addOnSuccessListener {
                for (c in it) {
                    defaultCategories.add(c.toObject(Category::class.java))
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Category: $defaultCategories")
                binding.recyclerViewIcons.adapter = CategoryIconAdapter(defaultCategories, this@OutflowTransactionFragment)
            }
```

I need this to work fast at least fast than reading from firestore online mode. and I want the online mode also to fetch the data locally from cached data instead of online for speed so when the device comes online it just update the catched data.

overall the desired result I want the speed.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple just by redirecting the call from the server to cache will do the magic.

If you are using Firestore in your app then you may notice a tiny delay in when you are getting data from Firestore in offline mode. and this because due to Firebase Firestore checks first in the  server the  data when it fails to load then again it takes the data  from cache.

The problem and the tiny delay is because of two calls. so to overcome the delay we need  get data from cache  and this very simple by passing `Source.CACHE` to `get()` method. The default call is always from server so we need to add  cache:

```
val source = Source.CACHE
firestore.collection(Constants.FireCollections.USERS)
   .document(FirebaseAuthRepository().getCurrentUserId())
   .collection("categories")
   .get(source).addOnSuccessListener {
       for (c in it) {
                        
       defaultCategories.add(c.toObject(Category::class.java))
      }
   Log.i(TAG, "Category: $defaultCategories")
   binding.recyclerViewIcons.adapter = CategoryIconAdapter(defaultCategories, this@OutflowTransactionFragment)
 }
```

Hope this help, let me know in the comment section if need for more clearification.

Comment: It is ok. But some of my users are facing that if cache is not synced then they don't see any data. But they are in active internet

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the hard side of Firestore, however, we can do our app intelligent by making appropriate calls in different scenarios to update the cache and keep it updated.

Comment: That means for cache and sync mechanism we should do some additional task manually right  , bhai?

Comment: Yes, you need to get your hand dirty writing some more 'guard coding' to ensure fast and reliable data transafer.